# Custom paging & sorting gridview

Tags: asp.net, objectdatasource

I am implementing custom sorting & paging for my gridview. On thing that baffles me is that

1. Why do we have to specify object datasource's filter column & filter column value (select parameters) in the total count method ?

Answer (score 1):

yes,

you have to specify selectmethod, CountMethod, Select Paramenter, SorExpression, Type name.

In select method you have to give Static - shared Method name where you have fired the query.

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server"

  EnablePaging="true" OnSelecting="ObjectDataSource1_Selecting"

  TypeName="WebApplication1.MinimalObjectDataSourceObject"

  SelectMethod="MinimalSelectMethod" SelectCountMethod="MinimalSelectCountMethod" />
```

CLASS DECLARATION

```
public class MinimalObjectDataSourceObject
{
    // A nice list for demonstration purposes.
    private static List<CultureInfo> baseList = new List<CultureInfo>(CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures));

    // Our minimal SelectMethod.

    public static List<CultureInfo> MinimalSelectMethod(string parameter1, string parameter2, int startRowIndex,
        int maximumRows)
    {
        List<CultureInfo> someList = GetSomeKindOfList(parameter1, parameter2);
        // Make sure we don't try to get objects that don't exist, ArgumentOutOfRangeException otherwise!
        if (startRowIndex + maximumRows > someList.Count)
        {
            maximumRows = someList.Count - startRowIndex;
        }

        return someList.GetRange(startRowIndex, maximumRows);
    }

    // Our minimal SelectCountMethod.

    public static int MinimalSelectCountMethod(string parameter1, string parameter2)
    {
        return GetSomeKindOfList(parameter1, parameter2).Count;
    }


    // A method to get a filtered list for our primary data source.

    public static List<CultureInfo> GetSomeKindOfList(string parameter1, string parameter2)
    {
        return baseList.FindAll(x => x.EnglishName.ToLower().StartsWith(parameter1))
            .FindAll(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameter2.ToLower()) ||
                          x.EnglishName.ToLower().EndsWith(parameter2.ToLower()));
    }
}
```